# Angular 2 – Acting on two BehaviorSubject / Observables

Tags: angular, rxjs

Suppose I have a component which needs two observables to render its content:

```
this.manifest.subscribe((a) => {
    f(a, b) 
})

this.route.params.subscribe((b) => {
    f(a, b)
})
```

What is the proper Angular / rxjs way to call `f()` once `a` arrives, and / or call it again once `b` (e.g., update on routing params) arrives.

Obviously I could keep track of `a` and `b` manually, but that looks ugly and not elegant. Is there a more Angularian way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `combineLatest` to merge the two streams and fire each time one of them fires.

```
Rx.Observable.combineLatest(this.manifest, this.route.params, (a, b) => f(a, b))
  .subscribe(c => /*Do something with the result of f(a,b)*/
```

Note that the above only fires once it has at least one value from each source, but I don't think that should be a problem if your sources are `BehaviorSubjects`

Answer (score 0):

If you need two observables to resolve one after the other you might want to consider `Observable.concat(obs1, obs2)`.

When subscribing to the concatenated observable, `obs1` will be subscribed to first, and then `obs2`.